# CompareGroup function in R _How to write the r code when the number of groups are more than five

Tags: r

I need to conduct the cluster mean comparison using "compareGroup" function. However, my r output says that the number of groups must be less than or equal 5.
how to increase the number of groups up to 6 since I have six clusters to be compared.

Comment: Where would the `compareGroup` function come from? Also, If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) its way easier for others to find and test a answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your information and quick response to my question. I use this link to have information in "compareGroup" command in R package. http://rstudio-pubs static.s3.amazonaws.com/234038_ad78275f926c4df3b90650308dfde194.html I just need to run the mean comparison for my six clusters using this command.  but it says total number of groups (clusters here) should be five or less. I think it is similar to one way ANOVA procedure but easy to use when there are categorical variables.